# Trigger to divide custom amount of account object amongst its child contacts

Tags: trigger, soql, account, contact

I have custom fields of `total_number__c` and total child contacts as `Total_money__c` in Account object and a custom field `IndividualMoney__c` in Contact. My aim is to distribute total amount to individual money equally between contacts.

Error facing :

> Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Total_money__c at line 22 column 42

```
trigger sharem on Contact(after insert, after update) {

    list < id > aid = new list < id > ();

    for (Contact cont: trigger.new) {

        aid.add(cont.accountid);

        list < Account > acc = [select id, name, total_number__c, Total_money__c from Account where id in: aid];
        list < Contact > co = [select id, name, IndividualMoney__c from contact where Accountid in: acc];
        list < Contact > updatco = new list < Contact > ();

        for (Contact upc: co) {
            upc.IndividualMoney__c = acc.Total_money__c / acc.total_number__c;
            updatco.add(upc);
        }
    }
    upsert updatco;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error. You are referencing fields on `Account`, `Total_money__c` and `total_number__c`, in a variable (`acc`) whose type is `List<Account>`.

You could fix this by extracting a single account from your list, but your trigger needs to be completely refactored to remove SOQL from the loop and bulkify the trigger. Please consider working through the entire [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_triggers) module on Trailhead and starting fresh with your queries outside the loop.